# Combine values and keys to form json object

Tags: c++, json, httpserver, jsoncpp

I have the keys and values as strings and i need to combine those into a json format.

For example : my `"keys"` string array is : `{"a","b","c","d"}`
my `"values"` string array i am getting through a for loop as it is stored in array `X`

```
X[0], X[1], X[2] and so on..
```

how do i combine `"keys"` and `"values"` to look like this:

```
{ "a":"x","b":"y", "c":"z", "d":"q"
}
```

I have tried iterating and combining but I'm stuck

```
std::string values="";
std::string keys[4]={"a","b","c","d"};
..
..
..
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    values= values + "," + x[i];
}
```

I'm confused as to how do i combine these two strings and display a resultant string that looks like this:

```
{ "a":"x",
  "b":"y",
  "c":"z",
  "d":"q"
}
```

Comment: You have added the `jsoncpp` tag to your question. That tag is for a specific JSON library for C++. There are also other JSON libraries you can use from C++ which can help you create JSON objects. I suggest you take some time to look for such libraries and how to use them.

Comment: will do that, thank you @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @KaranMotiramani: Please take a look at the JSON section here (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs). If you're comfortable with C++11 or later then JSON for Modern C++ (https://github.com/nlohmann/json) would be a good starting point.

Comment: I'd echo those above, never write a parser or writer for a standard file format unless you really have to, there is usually a library which already exists and has already found and fixed the bugs and edge cases

Comment: You should use a lib for parse or create a JSON string. And if you don't want 3rd:
std::string keys = {"a","b","c","d"};
std::string x = {"x","y","z","q"};
std::string values="{";
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    values += keys[i] + ":" + x[i];
    values += (i == 3) ? "}" : ",";
}

Comment: The content of your for loop should roughly be this: `values = values + keys[i] + "," + x[i] + ",";`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manual way can be done like:

```
std::string res = "{";
std::string keys[4]={"a","b","c","d"};
std::string values[4]={"a","b","c","d"};
const char* sep = "";

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    res += sep + keys[i] + ":" + values[i];
    sep = ",";
}
res += "}";
```

Using any json library, you might do something like:

```
Json::Value root(Json::ValueType::objectValue);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    root[keys[i]] = values[i];
}

Json::StyledWriter writer;
writer.write(root);
```